# ScaleAnimation in Android with api 23 and 25

Tags: android, animation

I'm currently running a strange issue in which this code:

```
public void animate(boolean expand) {
    ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(
            expand ? .25f : 1f, expand ? 1f : .25f,
            expand ? .25f : 1f, expand ? 1f : .25f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF , 1);
    scaleAnim.setDuration(500);
    scaleAnim.setRepeatCount(0);
    scaleAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    scaleAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    scaleAnim.setFillBefore(true);
    scaleAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
    myView.startAnimation(scaleAnim);
}
```

Works without issue on Android with 7+ (api: 25) but it's not working on 6 (api: 23).

I've tested with 5 different devices (OnePlus one, LG G5, Xperia z3 and z5) and 2 emulators. The method is posted on the UI thread at runtime within certain conditions but even assigning a listener to a button somewhere that trigger the method won't let the view animate. I've tried with `ObjectAnimators` with success however I need a `scaleAnim` for the pivot value. Anyone did experience similar issue?

Comment: `setPivotX()`: *"Sets the x location of the point around which the view is rotated and scaled"*, the same applies to `setPivotY`, so you can easily use an `ObjectAnimator` (or `AnimatorSet` for running 2 animators at a time)

Comment: I've tried with setPivotX from -1 to 100 but it wont scale to the bottom-end. It keeps scaling to the top-start

Comment: `pivotX float: The x location of the pivot point.` it is in pixels

Comment: That's ok, I can try to handle this using ObjectAnimator but still I want to understand why an api that's here since Android -1 it's having different behavior in 23 and 25

Comment: did `Animation.AnimationListener` worked at all? i mean methods: `onAnimationStart` / `onAnimationEnd` ? are they called if setup that listener?

Comment: yes! and also adding a postInvalidate() to the parent on start/end doesn't help

Comment: Didn't tried this.. but anyway, I must have it to true since im dealing with a webrtc client